# How many *distinct* cycles on a complete graph on a cube?

Tags: graph-theory

A cube has 8 vertices, so if there's an undirected complete graph on the cube then it has 16,036 possible simple cycles.

However most of these cycles are reflections or rotations of each other. Can someone help me figure out how many distinct cycles exist if we remove reflections or rotations?

E.g., on a square there are 14 possible simple cycles, but by inspection there are only 3 distinct shapes (triangle, square, and bow tie).

(To count the number of cycles I'm using $\sum_{k=3}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(k-1)!}{2}$ )

Comment: Have you heard about Burnside's lemma?

Comment: Thank you @Arthur, I had not, and it looks perfect for answering my question.